# Triple-State (or Multi-State) UI Object (Button)

Tags: buttons

Any ideas for how to design a multi-state UI "button"? The three states are:

- Off
- On, Selected
- On, Unselected

There needs to be a clear interaction difference between a user "Selecting" it and turning it "on" or "off".

*Some clarifications from the comments:*

On, Unselected means that the component driven by the button is 'On' or 'Enabled' but the controls/variables/view for that button is not in view (because it's not selected).

Off+Selected may be allowed, but for simplicity and to try out a design first I would rather keep it to just 3 states: Off, On+Selected, On+Unselected

Turning the component 'on' or 'off' is separate from the action of showing and hiding the variables associated with that component. Which is why the on/off interaction does not have to necessarily be part of the same button. However, there will be a handful of these buttons on the screen at any given moment, so it needs to be clear which button the user is actually turning on or off.

Any design patterns or inspirations you can think of?

For some more clarity, here is a wireframe example. The buttons in question are labeled A,B,C,D. There may be multiple "Controllers" on the page at any given time. The question is, what is a good way to allow the user to Turn On/Off one of the components (ABCD) and also to Select/Deselect...

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn1fkT.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: What does it mean to be 'on' and 'unselected'?

Comment: Is Off+Selected disallowed?

Comment: On, Unselected means that the component driven by the button is 'On' or 'Enabled' but the controls/variables/view for that button is not in view (because it's not selected).
  ----  
Off+Selected may be allowed, but for simplicity and to try out a design first I would rather keep it to just 3 states: Off, On+Selected, On+Unselected

Comment: It sounds like the action of turning the component 'on' or 'off' is separate from the action of showing and hiding the variables associated with that component. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, Matt, I think you're correct. Which is why the on/off interaction does not have to necessarily be part of the same button. However, there will be a handful of these buttons on the screen at any given moment, so it needs to be clear which button the user is actually turning on or off.

Comment: Please update your question with clarifications from the comments

Comment: honestly, I can't imagine your example, is it possible to explain it better or with an actual example?

Comment: Sorry PatomaS. I've added a Mockup to help illustrate what I'm talking about.

Comment: I think if you need to explain what the combinations mean, even if there's a way to clearly signal On+selected or Off+unselected, the user would still be confused as what the combinations mean. As such, it may be a better idea to just break into two sets of controls for clarity.

Answer (score 6):

If I'm right in my understanding that 'selected' isn't really a state (it's not a setting that is stored but rather something that happens within the UI to reduce the amount of information displayed) I'd consider something like the below. If a component is 'on', a control to expand the additional settings for that component is displayed.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fruTlw.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Ah, very interesting. You are right that 'selected' is not a stored state (only on/off is stored).The only reason why this does not work for my specific application is that a user can select more than one Component at a time (in order to edit multiple options at once for all the selected Components).

Comment: @Muers I see, that does certainly introduce another challenge...

Answer (score 3):

There are a ton of ways to show two states at once. Just choose any two visual properties, and map them to your variables.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx3V8I.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

In the mockup, I stuck to properties specific to the button, but you could go beyond that:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fntrgz.png)</sup>

But I have to say that this question is pretty general. A more specific description of your problem would help us in identifying a combination that works best for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

We are having a similar issue on one of our projects...we have recommended using a checkbox, but they are wanting something "sexier"...I'm sure you have all heard that before. I have a solution below, but I don't really care for it.

So we are thinking of something like this:
[image: Multi-state select]

Comment: That is an interesting approach. What do the different states/colors mean? It's not immediately obvious...

Comment: Red would mean "off," Blue-"on" and Grey="Neither on or off"...I would probably use different colors, but just wanted to get something out quick :).

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to accomplish that on canvas and configuration buttons at the same time, i think it'd be best to lower A (OFF) opacity to like .5 or .3, then use color code for B & D (ON & Selected) and C (ON & Unselected). As of the part where you input values, it would be almost the same, but using the toggle concept to switch between ON - OF. It's still color coding though :)

Sorry if the explanation is too complicated, hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On / Off is associated to the checkbox kind of button.
Unselected is associated to grayed appearance of a disabled control.

One way to do what you want would be to set big checkbox-like controls to signal On / Off states, and to enable /disable them to signal selected / not-selected states.

Not the natural checkbox found in the wild, awful and intractable.
To be able to tweak the appearance of checkboxes you need a wrapper, like [jQueryUI button](http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox) or something similar, allowing you to style them at will.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a circle. Off is a plain black border, on but unselected is a thicker, colored border, and on and selected is a solid color. Simple, and should be usable by anyone. Should scale fairly well, unless you want to use two dozen on a mobile UI (but then, I think most options will give you trouble in this case).