# Activating/deactivating functionality with additional settings

Tags: gui-design

I'm working on an application which is split up in several features which can be activated or deactivated. The user can activate or deactivate the functionality but when activated he has to fill some additional required settings. The section containing the settings should be expandable and collapsible but only when the functionality is activated. I'm thinking about a [+] / [-] icon and a clickable label which opens the section with additional settings. It's probably the most friendly options but it's dead ugly imho. Any ideas for a better friendly solution?

Comment: How about including a mock-up of what you are thinking to give everyone a visual to go off of.

Comment: Something vaguely like this? http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/28202/10615

Comment: That's interesting. It's shows what I like to achieve. There can also be nested fields. One toggle activates additional settings and one of the settings can make other settings visible.

Answer (score 1):

How about an on/off switch, which toggles the more specific settings to expand/collapse?

This would be similar to what Matt Obee suggested except that the expand/collapse would be built in to turning each piece on/off. (Rather than having two separate controls for this.)